# Variable out of IBAction

Tags: objective-c, xcode, variables, double, ibaction

I have problem that im trying to get solve for like week.
My goal is to get variable out of my `IBAction`, to use for example in `-(void)viewDidLoad`..
But as far as I am now I can use my variable only in my `IBAction`..

```
- (IBAction) changeLat:(NSNumber *)str {

longi =  str; 
double lop = longi.doubleValue;

NSLog(@"%f",lop);
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

NSLog (@"%@",lop);
}
```

It `NSLog` shows everything fine in action, but in view did load it doesn't even recorganize it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, `IBAction` is converted to `void` by the preprocessor. It's used by Interface Builder as a label that identifies this method as an action able to be related from an IB Object.

There's no way (AFAIK) to use two return types in a function (for example `(IBAction double)´, equivalent to ´(void double)´), but a good practice could be something like this:

```
- (IBAction)changeLatAction:(id)sender {
    NSNumber *str = <get the NSNumber from a valid place>;
    [self changeLat:str];
}

- (double) changeLat:(NSNumber *)str {
    longi =  str; 
    double lop = longi.doubleValue;
    NSLog(@"%f",lop);
    return ????;
}
```

Your first declaration of `changeLat` seems to be wrong, because as a first parameter you'll always get the "sender" or "caller" object, related from IB (when called from an action, of course), so, you need to get the `str` value from a valid place.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you create a variable inside of -IBAction, the scope of that variable is only that method, so you cannot access to that variable outside it.

If you want your variable to be global to your class, you have to create it in the declaration of your class, like this:

```
@interface MainViewController () {
@private
    double lop;

}
```

Put this at the beginning of your .m file, and then lop would be accesible in all your class.

You can read more about the scope of the variables here:

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Objective-C_Variable_Scope_and_Storage_Class